# SQLite Exception Path does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to connect an already existing SQLite database to my java project, as a temporary solution for testing a simple log-in dialog. Here is my connector class:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SQLite_login_connector {
//Initializes global connection variable (unused until now!)
Connection conn_log = null;

public static Connection logindb_connection(){

    //Simple try catch block that prints error trace log in a JOptionPane if runtime error occurs.

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        Connection conn_log = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/SQLite/ISRSMS_Login.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful!");
        return conn_log;

    }   catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }       
  }
 }
```

My SQLite database is located in a folder within my project folder:

[image: Project folder with SQLite database]

When I try running my connector class, it throws the following exception:

[image: JMessageDialog with Eception e printed]

For me it looks as if it assumes that the folder which contains my database is located on my F: drive, as opposed to my root project in my local repository. I have tried putting the database into my src folder, as well as into a new resource folder all-together. Every time it throws the same exception. Why does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have metntioned / in yor connection string it is pointing to the root directory of your drive 
Remove the / in your connection string Do as follows

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:SQLite/ISRSMS_Login.sqlite")
```

For your convenience please follow the naming convention of java language
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Thanks, I now feel stupid. I somehow have managed to not notice the / while copying he path. Sorry for wasting time!

Comment: And as for the Class names, thanks for the suggestion, but they were a given for me, since another contributor to our repo requested me to use them. I consider them pretty nasty as well

Answer (score 0):

Why is your URL .sqllite? I would expect .db - [like here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite/Connecting)

```
jdbc:sqlite:C:/mydir/mydb.db
```

Comment: .sqlite is the standard extension given to sqlite databases created using the firefox-based sqlite manager. It usually creates no problems and is as valid as .db. My problem lay within me overseeing that I copied the / in front of the SQLite folder path. Thanks for attempting to help though!